# How to programmatically render a contact form in a theme in D8

Tags: 8, entities, theming, emails

How to get the side-wide contact form (feedback) individually displayed in a custom block or other page then /contact (e.g. frontpage)?

I've tried this code, but it is not working (are contact forms entities?):

```
// get default form
// get the entity object
$default_form = \Drupal::config('contact.settings')->get('default_form');
$entity = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('contact_form')->load($default_form);

// get view builder
// render view
$view_builder = \Drupal::entityManager()->getViewBuilder('contact_form');
$full_output = $view_builder->view($entity);
```

Comment: INFO: 1) the default side-wide contact form (feedback) is an entity (not so the login form). 2) `entityManager` is deprecated in favour of `entityTypeManager` ([API docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal.php/function/Drupal%3A%3AentityManager/8))

Comment: I would like to refer to a new main D8 question to help with all sub-questions like this here, caused by the open basic question, well documented here in details: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/197149/updated-da-drupal-8-0-5-rendering-forms-entities-programmatically-on-theming

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Contact form is an entity, but you can't view it.

What you want instead is an add form of a contact_message with contact_form as bundle.

See `ContactController::contactSitePage()` (EDIT: [API docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!contact!src!Controller!ContactController.php/class/ContactController/8)) as example:

```
$message = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('contact_message')
  ->create(array(
    'contact_form' => $contact_form->id(),
  ));

// This works in a controller, use \Drupal::service('entity.form_builder') elsewhere.
$form = $this->entityFormBuilder()->getForm($message);
$form['#title'] = SafeMarkup::checkPlain($contact_form->label());
```

EDIT (thanks @nilsun): Note that entityManager is deprecated in favour of entityTypeManager.

Comment: INFO: `entityManager` is deprecated in favour of `entityTypeManager` ([API docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal.php/function/Drupal%3A%3AentityManager/8)) and some links are missing here in the answer. In the answer it states: **See** `ContactController::contactSitePage()` as example. Where is it? Is it a doc page on Drupal.org? Is it a function in core? How to implement this in a preprocess function since the question was about .theme? Things have changed end of last year and there are missing informations about the final D8 core regarding such questions in most answers.

Comment: I would like to refer to a new main D8 question to help with all sub-questions like this here, caused by the open basic question, well documented here in details: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/197149/updated-da-drupal-8-0-5-rendering-forms-entities-programmatically-on-theming

Comment: String::checkPlain is now SafeMarkup::checkPlain

Comment: @pcambra Thanks, note that anyone can update answers, you can just fix something like that yourself.