# Programmatically get a form in Drupal 8

Tags: 8

The [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2117411) states:

> The argument passed to the getForm() method is the name of the class
>   that defines your form and is an implementation of
>   \Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilderInterface.

How do I find out the name of the class that defines the *website feedback form* provided by the core *contact* module (the form id is: `feedback_contact_message_form`).

When I `dpm()` the form I can see that there is a class defined:

```
$input array(30)
  →'#attributes' => array(1)
    →'class' => array(3)
      string(29) "feedback-contact-message-form"
      string(20) "contact-message-form"
      string(12) "contact-form"
```

I tried various forms of this as the parameter to pass to:

```
\Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm();
```

but no luck. Thanks

Comment: Contact forms are entities, so I'd imagine they all come from `Drupal\contact\ContactFormEditForm`. Not sure there's an easy way to find that out unless you know it's an entity form though. The best way might be to look under the module's `src` folder for files whose name ends with `Form.php`. I think that's a safe convention to follow

Comment: Wouldn't Berdir's answer in my question help? http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/146617/how-to-render-a-contact-form-in-a-theme

Comment: Thanks, but I don't follow Berdir's answer. I've added my block plugin below my answer - adding the first two lines from your code sample. Where do I go from here? Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

This renders within a block plugin:

```
class myModule extends BlockBase {
  public function build() {

    $default_form = \Drupal::config('contact.settings')->get('default_form');
    $entity = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('contact_form')->load($default_form);

    $message = \Drupal::entityManager()
      ->getStorage('contact_message')
      ->create(array(
        'contact_form' => $entity->id(),
      ));

    $form = \Drupal::service('entity.form_builder')->getForm($message);

    return $form;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue. can we share notes and chat? All I want to do is just take a form from somwhere on the site and output it somewhere else inside a PHP enabled text field.

Comment: How I can submit this entity form programatically?

Comment: if the form needs to act on #after_build, for ajax operation, do we have any solution?