# Rendering contact_form

Tags: forms, 8, emails

I have call my current contactform with this function in mytheme.theme.

```
$form = Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('contact_form');
```

I have this

```
object(Drupal\contact\Entity\ContactForm)#412 (23) {
  ["id":protected]=>
  string(8) "feedback"
  ["label":protected]=>
  string(14) "Nous contacter"
  ["recipients":protected]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(21) "mymail@gmail.com"
  }
  ["reply":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["weight":protected]=>
  int(0)
  ["originalId":protected]=>
  string(8) "feedback"
  ["pluginConfigKey":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["status":protected]=>
  bool(true)
  ["uuid":protected]=>
  string(36) "6e997e8b-9d85-4e59-9e43-67004270fe13"
  ["isSyncing":"Drupal\Core\Config\Entity\ConfigEntityBase":private]=>
  bool(false)
  ["isUninstalling":"Drupal\Core\Config\Entity\ConfigEntityBase":private]=>
  bool(false)
  ["langcode":protected]=>
  string(2) "fr"
  ["third_party_settings":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["_core":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["trustedData":protected]=>
  bool(false)
  ["entityTypeId":protected]=>
  string(12) "contact_form"
  ["enforceIsNew":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["typedData":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["cacheContexts":protected]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(28) "languages:language_interface"
  }
  ["cacheTags":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["cacheMaxAge":protected]=>
  int(-1)
  ["_serviceIds":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["dependencies":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

But how can I rendering this ? My goal is to render the current contact form.

Edit1: I have tried this [How to programmatically render a contact form in a theme in D8](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/146617/how-to-render-a-contact-form-in-a-theme)

But when I try this

```
    $form = Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('contact_form');//get the current form called
    $message = \Drupal::entityManager()
      ->getStorage('contact_message')
      ->create(array(
        'contact_form' => $form->id(),
      ));
//$form->id() = 'feedback'
        $form = Drupal::service('entity.form_builder')->getForm($message);
```

I have a very big array (Firefox and Chrome crash when in print them )

When I try this

```
$form = Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('contact_form');//get the current form called
ContactController::contactSitePage($form);
```

I have this error

```
PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function getStorage() on null in /var/www/drupal8/core/modules/contact/src/Controller/ContactController.php on line 83
```

**Why I would like to do this in my .theme file ?**

Because I have begin to migrate a website in drupal 6 to drupal 8 .(I have try [Drupal Upgrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_upgrade) and they works very good ) The page of this website has been built with a little home framework. It call many others not Drupal script. With this, not Drupal Script (Ex:tagada.com/horoscope.php ) and drupal page ( tagada.com/drupalpart/node/10) works with same css and html structure file in a external folder. In Drupal6 the theme worked correctly with a global variable object with node content `$node`

Comment: Have you try it out `drupal_render `? I do not know if that works or not.

Comment: Rendering is not the problem, you need to get the build array of the form, see http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/146617/how-to-render-a-contact-form-in-a-theme

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! I am sorry, but you need to provide more details, to ask a question. A single line of code, without knowing where you are using it, is not a question. Also, in general themes don't use code like that.

Comment: With contact_storage module, you can use an entity reference field to render it

Comment: @kiamlaluno Tank's for your answer I have write more details in Edit1

Comment: @darol100 drupal_render is Deprecated with drupal8 https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!includes!common.inc/function/drupal_render/8

Comment: @4k4 I have answer in Edit1 why they doesent works to me

Comment: @larowlan Tanks to your answer I'm go to [api Entity Reference Drupal 8](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!Plugin!DataType!EntityReference.php/class/EntityReference/8) and to [drupal project contact storage](https://www.drupal.org/project/contact_storage) but I don't understand what to do.

Comment: ... and is it just me, or is he replacing $form var value twice in his code?

Comment: I would like to refer to a new main D8 question to help with all sub-questions like this here, caused by the open basic question, well documented here in details: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/197149/updated-da-drupal-8-0-5-rendering-forms-entities-programmatically-on-theming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finnaly I have find the answer to my problem's .

**It was a drupal permission problem's .**

User Anonymous users do not have permission to use the general contact form. I gave permission and everything worked .

Thank you alot for the advice .

Comment: I would like to refer to a new main D8 question to help with all sub-questions like this here, caused by the open basic question, well documented here in details: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/197149/updated-da-drupal-8-0-5-rendering-forms-entities-programmatically-on-theming